# finding sum of odd numbers

Tags: python, python-3.x

mystery_int = 7

unable to get this loop, keep modifiyng code only to get error message. Does anyone have any suggestions?

```
while mystery_int in range(mystery_int):
    if mystery_int > 0:
        mystery_int = sum(range(0, mystery_int + 2))
    if mystery_int < 0:
        mystery_int = sum(range(mystery_int, 0))
    print(mystery_int)
```

Comment: what do you want to do?

Comment: Do the code and the question title have any relation?

Comment: What was the error message?

Comment: By the way this will always be `False`:  `mystery_int in range(mystery_int)` since the range will be reevaluated on every iteration.

Comment: I am attempting to make a loop that will add the sum of the of the numbers between 0 and the variable mystery_int. so if mystery_int is 7, we would get 28. if the number is negative (for example -3) we would get the corresponding negative value in this case -6.

Comment: just do `import math;(lambda x: math.copysign(sum(range(abs(x)+1)),x))(7)` or simply create a function: `b = lambda x: math.copysign(sum(range(abs(x)+1)),x)` now use the function `b(7);b(-3)` etc

Answer (score 1):

`sum(range(mystery_int, 0)` has two opening parentheses, and one closing. Also, `range` goes from `0` to one less than the input; thus, `mystery_int` is not in `range(mystery_int)` and the loop never runs. And using the same variable name to represent two different things, as in `mystery_int in range(mystery_int)`, is a bad idea.

Comment: i know using the variable of the same name to represent two different things isnt the best practice although any other variable I use ends up genrating a name error saying "x" or whatever else i use isnt defined.

Answer (score 0):

```
mystery_int=7
while mystery_int in range(0,100):
      print(mystery_int)
```

you declared mystery_int=7 and you are taking the range as mystery_int which is not good,try using other range, and if your value mystery_int=7 is in range,it will create
 infinite loop as you already taken mmystery_int=7.

Answer (score 0):

Changing the loop from `while` to `for` this worked for me (I also moved the `print` function out of the loop.

```
mystery_int = 7
for mystery_int in range(mystery_int):
    if mystery_int > 0:
        mystery_int = sum(range(0, mystery_int + 2))
    if mystery_int < 0:
        mystery_int = sum(range(mystery_int, 0))
print(mystery_int)
```

But this doesn't do what you describe in your comments for negative values, the following works for both signs:

```
mystery_int = 7
if mystery_int > 0:
    mystery_sign = 1
if mystery_int < 0:
    mystery_int*=-1
    mystery_sign = -1
for mystery_i in range(mystery_int):
    mystery_int = sum(range(0, mystery_i + 2))
print(mystery_int*mystery_sign)
```

Comment: this is beautiful, i never thought to create a second variable to use. thanks! helped alot.

Comment: @christopher, I'm glad this helped. If this response worked, please mark it as accepted. That and up-vote is how we express our gratitude here.